# Can't close Robe console split in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, enh-ruby-mode

I run `SPC m s i` to start Robe (Ruby code inspection tool) in spacemacs, and it opens a split with a REPL. When I'm done issuing commands I can't close the split.

- `SPC` is not usable because the REPL and the buffer are just interpreting what I type as text, it just outputs whitespace.
- I can stop the console process with `C-c C-\` but then I'm still left with an open split and the buffer still ignoring `SPC`.

How do I close the other split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of emacs and vim commands fixed this. I had to kill the process (that was swallowing all the `SPC` keypresses) with `C-c C-\` and then press `ESC` to get out of insert mode. Then I could just use `:q` to exit the split.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not in insert mode in the REPL?  If so, just hit ESC to go to normal mode.  Then SPC won't be swallowed any more.